# What are the BLE (Bluetooth 4.0) module names?

Tags: iphone, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to know the bluetooth module names that are compatible with iPhone 4S. I read in many articles that iPhone 4S have BLE and it can be connected to noniOS devices. What are the BLE modules name available?

Comment: Any BLE module is compatible, that is one of the best features of BLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BLE112 by Bluegiga is currently the most popular and easiest to find module:
http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bluegiga-Technologies/BLE112-A/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMt1Kg3wsyvxe2VNUu4igQjl

It works well with iOS.

Comment: BLED112 is actually an USB dongle. The module is BLE112...

Comment: spamsink: you are absolutely right - I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

The BLE112 module is based on TI CC2540 radio chip, but has custom stack. The best documented stack so far is the TI, Texas Instruments has a wiki, pretty good packet sniffer http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/BLE_sniffer_guide, and the stack actually works! The same radio - CC2540 or CC2541 is used in Panasonic modules (search CC254 on DigiKey or Mouser). Avoid BlueRadios, uses the same chip, but they have their own stack, and are super secretive about it - before they give you access to anything, they want a copy of an invoice - proof you bought their stuff.

Comment: Coming from desktop development world, TI documentation is so bad I hardly can think of a comparison. Adobe, maybe. Their software dev guide doesn't match UUID and handles of actual samples. They don't proof read hteir docs. The big problem is that other manufactures have none. So TI looks good.

Comment: I would second the advice to stay away from BlueRadios. Their product support (or total lack thereof) is horrible. BlueGiga's equivalent module is cheaper too.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectBlue's OLP425 (also based on the 2540) module (http://support.connectblue.com/display/Dashboard/OLP425) is another alternative.

Their dev kit (CB-OLP425I-26-A) is $66 from DigiKey http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DKSearch/dksus.dllDetail&itemSeq=133228274&uq=635089739906227723

You'll need a TI CC Debugger ($50 from DigiKey)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, there are alternatives to designs based on TI 2540/41. For example, Nordic Semi has a number of [third party modules](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/3rd-Party-Bluetooth-Smart-Modules) available. There is even a [BLE Arduino](http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/) shield based on their chip.